# Generating aarch64 RPM package from yocto SDK

Tags: cmake, yocto, rpm, cpack

I am running Ubuntu 18:04 x86_64 in Docker.
I have copied and sourced SDK I have produced with Yocto.

```
source /sdk/environment-setup-aarch64-poky-linux
```

I am compiling my library

```
cmake .. -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release
cmake --build .
```

Everything is fine so far, when I check the lib architecture `file myLib.so` it says aarch64

```
myLib.so: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, ARM aarch64, version 1 (GNU/Linux), dynamically linked, BuildID[sha1]=5e01090be56b47a2dd2edd7c44e9861709f3090a, with debug_info, not stripped
```

Now I want to generate RPM package using `cpack -G "RPM"`

```
-- Toolchain file defaulted to '/sdk/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/share/cmake/OEToolchainConfig.cmake'
CPack: Create package using RPM
CPack: Install projects
CPack: - Run preinstall target for: myLib
CPack: - Install project: myLib
CPack: Create package
-- CPackRPM:Debug: Using CPACK_RPM_ROOTDIR=/myLib/build/_CPack_Packages/Linux/RPM
CPackRPM: Will use GENERATED spec file: /myLib/build/_CPack_Packages/Linux/RPM/SPECS/myLib.spec
CPack: - package: /myLib/build/myLib.rpm generated.
```

The result of the rpm file when I check it with `rpm -qi myLib.so` is

```
Name        : myLib
Version     : 1.1.1
Release     : 1
Architecture: x86_64
...
```

Why is the architecture of RPM file x86_64?
What am I missing for the cpack to produce aarch64 RPM file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable [CPACK_RPM_PACKAGE_ARCHITECTURE](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.11/module/CPackRPM.html#variable:CPACK_RPM_PACKAGE_ARCHITECTURE) defaults to `uname -m` which is currently set to the architecture of your computer. You can manually set this variable to override the package architecture.

`CPACK_RPM_PACKAGE_ARCHITECTURE=aarch64 cpack -G "RPM"`

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you very much.
Nevertheless setting env variable does not work for me, I have to set variable in CMake ```set(CPACK_RPM_PACKAGE_ARCHITECTURE aarch64)```or pass it to CMake with -D ```cmake .. -DCPACK_RPM_PACKAGE_ARCHITECTURE=aarch64```